# Trading using Simple Moving Average strategy

Tags: stocks, trading, day-trading

I am trying to understand the concepts for applying the Simple Moving Average principles for identifying buying/selling points for stocks.

I have the calculations down for getting the Simple Moving Average, I just don't know how to apply it (or use its value) to find the triggers/signals for buying and selling.  I have watched multiple videos, and read articles, but I feel like I am missing something.  Can anyone simply explain how to use the value of the Simple Moving Average for determining to buy or sell a certain stock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you had some losing trades while using the MAs as indicators. However, you need to keep in mind some important points:

- You should use simple moving averages along side other indicators and not alone. For example, you can use the 200 MA along side the RSI to identify an oversold condition.
- Different indicators are useful during different market conditions. For example, moving averages are great if you are trading a stock which is trending down or trending up. But if a stock is trading side-ways, then you are better off using other indicators such as the Stochastic RSI.
- I would advise against using MAs on very short timescales such as the 1 and 5 minute charts as you can get a lot of false signals. Now that I have learned from past mistakes, I prefer to trade the daily chart. A lot less stressful and better probability of success.

Like you, I am still learning how to trade, even though I have been doing it for a few years now. The learning never ends. I wrote an article about using simple moving averages. Maybe you find it useful: https://nullbeans.com/what-is-a-simple-moving-average-sma-in-trading/

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice, this is great info. I wanted to get further info from you about one of the details you mentioned ‘I prefer to trade the daily charts’ and wanted to see what you meant (sorry I am newer to technical analysis and using the data to determine buy/sell indicators).  Any advice is appreciated, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am glad you found the information useful. In chart analysis you have the choice of plotting the stock price chart on a 5 mins, 15 mins, 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week.. candles. If you look at the 5 minute chart you will see a lot of price fluctuations which could produce false trading signals. However, if you go to the 1 day chart, the signals that you get from RSI, MAs and all the other indicators will be more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

A moving average (MA) reduces the amount of noise in a price chart.  The longer the period, the greater the smoothing and the fewer the number of whipsaws.  The drawback of a longer period is that the signals are delayed so that you are late in and late out.  Use a shorter period and you'll be more timely but you'll have a lot of bad trades from whipsaws.

A simple moving average weights all periods equally so there is a drop off affect (as today's value is added, the value for the oldest day is removed).  Because of this, the value of today's SMA  can be affected by the new value, the removed value or a combination of both.   An exponential moving average minimizes the drop off factor by  weighting the most  recent price more.

Here's the problem with MA systems.  The time frame that you select determines  how effective the MA is (lag versus whipsaws).  The success of any moving average crossover systems is dependent on selecting the right periodicity and that is only known in hindsight. Past performance is no guarantee of future  results

Here's a learning exercise for you.  Obtain several years of SPY or DIA data and optimize to determine the ideal MA for the first 1/4 of the data.  Now test that ideal MA against the next three 1/4 periods of the data.  Odds are, you're going to obtain disappointing results.

Entire books have been written on moving average crossover systems  so you're not going to get a short, accurate answer here or from any web site.

Exploring this and other trading ideas is worthwhile but don't implement any of them unless  you fully grasp the pros and cons of them.

Comment: Bob, that’s great info. I really appreciate it. Are there any patterns or strategies that you recommend or have found success with for use with charting patterns that have proven helpful for targeting buy/sell before hand that can be used to help predict patterns? It seems like there are sooooo many and I am not familiar enough with which ones are worth focusing time on. I appreciate your advice and help.

Comment: AFAIC, no pattern is reliable enough to consistently make money over time.  If one did exist, the big traders  would find it, trade it, and it would cease to work. Chart patterns and technical analysis can provide useful information like support and resistance, current trend, current momentum but they are a reflection of past price and/or volume movement and they predict absolutely nothing going forward.  Any trade taken is a hope that the trend will continue.  Trade off of price, volatility  and news. You're likely to do much better. And if you can't, just invest.

Comment: Bob, that is great, I really appreciate the advice.  Thanks so much.

Comment: For a good review see http://www.philosophicaleconomics.com/2016/01/gtt/ and https://movement.capital/getting-real-about-trend-following-returns/. From my own analysis and study, it is very unlikely that you will "beat the market" with trend following, but rather the purpose is to protect from large drawdowns.

Comment: TLDNR most of it.  A study like that based on an assumption that  selling one month before the onset of a recession and buying one month after is some kind of reasonable foundation for timing recessions.  The market often moves down for longer periods of time before a recession begins as well as a up  a significant amount long before it ends. Each recession is different.